# Parse JSON to Array from URL using GSON

Tags: java, json, yql

Good evening,

I'm looking to parse a JSON block I get from yahoo.finance.quote through a YQL request into a list to be used with a SQL DB.

Here is the relevant block of code:

```
String uri = "(\"GOOG\",\"YHOO\",\"AAPL\",\"C\",\"FB\",\"GE\",\"BAC\")";

String yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20" + uri + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";  


        BufferedReader reader = null;
            URL url = new URL(yql);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            Class1 data = gson.fromJson(reader, Class1.class);
            System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(data));

public class Class1 {
      private int query;
      private int results;
      private List<Class2> quote;
    }

    public class Class2 {
      private String Name;
    }
```

The actual data I want from the JSON is Data.Query.Result.Quote, but I cannot seem to reference this properly using Inner Classes (Class1, Class2). Could anyone provide some assistance, or let me know if I'm doing something silly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Query` , `results` and `quote` are `JSONObject`s in their own right. You cannot map them this way and expect it to work. Use this structure as a reference and complete the rest.

## Parse

```
Response fromJson = gson.fromJson(file, Response.class);
System.out.println(fromJson.getQuery().getResults().getQuote().getSymbol());
```

## Output

> GOOG

## Structure

```
public class Response
{
    private Query query;

    public Query getQuery()
    {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(Query query)
    {
        this.query = query;
    }

}

class Query 
{
    private int count;
    private Results results;
    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public Results getResults()
    {
        return results;
    }
    public void setResults(Results results)
    {
        this.results = results;
    }


}

class Results
{
    private Quote quote;

    public Quote getQuote()
    {
        return quote;
    }

    public void setQuote(Quote quote)
    {
        this.quote = quote;
    }


}

class Quote
{
    private String symbol;

    public String getSymbol()
    {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol)
    {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
}
```

Comment: THank you for your help, I'm getting a null pointer error from the print line, can I read in a BufferedReader like I have in my original code, or does it need to be a file, as you've specified.

Comment: @JCG it can be a `BufferedReader` but you will need to handle cases where elements are missing (they can be `null`).